# Wordpress Keeps Logging Out - What Tests Can I Run to Solve This?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, cookies, session, logout

I keep getting logged out of wordpress randomly. Despite having set long "Remember Me" times etc. I am still being required to log back in when I re-open my browser and whilst in admin, I randomly get the login pop-up asking me to log back in.

I believe this started occurring around the time of the latest Woocommerce update (the big one) but it could have been something else.

How can I monitor what is happening so I can figure out why things aren't being saved and I keep being logged out?

Comment: Have you spoken with WooCommerce support about this? 3rd party dev support is offtopic and out of scope here

Comment: No, but its because I'm not positive it is a Woocommerce issue... just a hunch.

Are you aware of any way I can monitor whats happening with cookies to try and debug the error?

Comment: If you disable WooCommerce or downgrade does the problem go away? What you're describing is not standard WordPress behaviour, all I can suggest is that you check the cookie expiration in the browser dev tools. Otherwise, you're going to have to either identify the cause via a process of elimination, or conduct a line by line code review of the entire site. Right now i don't see a way to answer this factually unless the answer happens to identify your cause, I don't believe it's possible to say Do X Y or Z and you'll find the culprit. This isn't a discussion forum :/

Comment: Otherwise the number of potential sources for what could be causing this are too numerous, it could be something as esoteric as CDN caching rules if you use something like CloudFlare. In order to continue, you need to identify if your sessions are being cleared, ended, or if they're simply on short expiration, Those are all unique problems, e.g. the first one could be caused by overzealous browser privacy settings. It's simplu too broad and expansive, narrow the question down to something specific that can be factually and concretely answered in isolation